# The Server Fault Wiki of recommended practices

Tags: discussion

So I've noticed that there are several recommendations on basic practices on Server Fault, but there doesn't seem to be a cohesive view as to how those recommendations would all fit together.  So I thought I would lump these together as a kind of mental exercise to see what the "ServerFault Community IT Department" would look like if it were implemented.  This would give a few things: it would make a reasonable wiki (in the true wiki spirit of many contributions), it would provide several links to well-vetted practices, and it would be kind of fun to see what the amalgamation would look like.  And who knows, it may even point out some interesting issues between different forms of "best practices", although I would be stunned if there was a conflict hidden in there someplace...

Add your favorites from Server Fault as answers, and I'll re-edit this section with the results.  Here's a few catagories to collect different ideas together.

Hardware Configuration(s)

- [Server room configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/331/the-perfect-server-room).
- [Server room temperature](https://serverfault.com/questions/11145/what-is-the-correct-temperature-for-a-server-room)
- [Firmware Updates and Scheduling](https://serverfault.com/questions/28017/firmware-best-practices-and-update-schedules)

Storage Configuration(s)

- [Selecting a NAS box](https://serverfault.com/questions/28370/choosing-a-nas-system-and-things-to-watchout-for)
- [Linux: Dealing with /tmp](https://serverfault.com/questions/8427/linux-unix-server-setup-practices-for-tmp)
- [Linux: Install apps in /var or /opt?](https://serverfault.com/questions/96416/should-i-install-linux-applications-in-var-or-opt)

Network Configuration(s)

- [checking DNS health and compliance](https://serverfault.com/questions/39916/check-public-dns-health-and-rfc-compliance)

Security Practice(s)

- [Password (General) Best Practices](https://serverfault.com/questions/5589/password-best-practices)
- [Password sharing methods](https://serverfault.com/questions/10285/best-practise-and-solutions-for-sharing-passwords)
- [Windows Update](https://serverfault.com/questions/30647/windows-update-best-practices)
- [Updating Windows Servers that are hosts for VMs](https://serverfault.com/questions/67106/updating-windows-servers)

Network Service(s)

User Service(s)

- [User Naming & Deletion](https://serverfault.com/questions/42204/best-practices-or-experience-with-company-wide-username-policies-and-resolving-du)

Upgrade Process(es)

Disaster Recovery

- [Checking Backups](https://serverfault.com/questions/5049/best-practices-for-backup-checking)
- [Documenting an outage for a post-mortem review](https://serverfault.com/questions/29188/documenting-an-outage-for-a-post-mortem-review)

Last Edit: 2010-02-17

Comment: A better way would be to just tag those questions "best-practices".  That way you can just refer to the tag search: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/best-practices and be done with it. Much less clutter and work for all.

Comment: Then I have to open each and every one to find "the answer".  Tagging is great from a "self-organizing" perspective, but it's the lazy way out, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with David. Let's have some best-practices tags too.

Comment: Very well.  Tags are nice, but I find they are a lot more effort to sift through than to have a one-stop-shop page that has all of the relevant links on it.  The second goal was to do a little mental exercise, if all of the recommendations from SF were used to run a conceptualized group of servers for some purpose, what would that look like?  But if everyone's for tags, I won't buck the trend, so I'll close the question.  How's this: if I don't get another bite in a week's time, I'll close it, fair enough?

Comment: Looks like we're going to close this, unless there's some action in the next 12 hours.  Anyone care to post?

Comment: Jeff, we have a quandry here. There have been no postings, but I suddenly find that at least 7 people are interested in this question and 8 more have marked it as "favorite". Guess it's time to haul out a bounty? (hauls out a 50-point chunk of flesh) ouch!  That stings.  Well, let's see what happens.

Comment: Whelp, it looks like another quandry: I can either punish myself by deleting or closing the question and loose the bounty I put into this, or I can answer the question myself to salvage the failed bounty attempt, but I don't like do thing that.  So, what should happen?  Seems like no-one is going to do anything, and I don't see why it should be fair that I'm punished for trying to do something "nice" for the community.

Comment: Lesson learned: if you start a pure-play community wiki, no-one will come.  If you start it, upvote people, then convert it, people will rain suggestions on you from everywhere.  This is a big problem in my eyes, and I'm starting to think that the "wiki" concept needs a lot of rework.

Comment: (sigh) wow...and so it begins.  Voting to close this.

Comment: Funny what you stumble on in the older articles...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding a link to [Documenting an Outage for a Post-Mortem Review](https://serverfault.com/questions/29188/documenting-an-outage-for-a-post-mortem-review) as well?

Answer (score 2):

Under security Practices:
[Best Practice and Solutions for Sharing Passwords](https://serverfault.com/questions/10285/best-practise-and-solutions-for-sharing-passwords)

Answer (score 2):

You could start with consolidating other questions on the site:  [The Perfect Server Room](https://serverfault.com/questions/331/the-perfect-server-room)

Comment: That's certainly the idea. :)  But it's a large task to do this, and I want people to nominate what they think is important.  A quick glance at the question section shows there are several thousand questions, but only a few are best-practice related.  I figured, this would make a handy place to aggregate those answers together, instead of having to search for each one.  So, I'm willing to add answers and maintain this for a bit, if people are willing to chip in a little bit.